# Does "manicure" only apply to caring for hands?

Tags: etymology

I understand that *manicure* derives from the Latin for *hand* and *to care for*, but can *manicure* mean *care for by hand*? So could you manicure a bush?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(from a [Yahoo Answers post](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080709223409AAFaX8J))

> The words pedicure and manicure are derived from Latin words. Pedicure came from the latin word pedis meaning feet and cura meaning care. Thus pedicure means the care of the feet. Manicure came from the latin word manus meaning hands and, again cura, meaning care. So manicure is the care of the hands.

But as others have indicated, whereas "pedicure" *only ever* applies to feet, "manicure" can be metaphorically applied to such things as lawns, ornamental bushes, and pubic hair. And nose and ear hair – for which you often get suitable implements in a [manicure set.](http://uk.strawberrynet.com/mens-skincare/the-art-of-shaving/manicure-set--nail-file---nose/100367/)

Moving further into metaphorical territory, a Google search produces quite a few hits for "manicured flower beds", "borders", "fields", and even "fiction" and "manners".

Comment: +1 for the application of *manicure* to pubic hair. There's a slang term involved here that is very close to the wording of the question that I'm not willing to touch.  Manicure can also apply to facial hair, by the way.

Comment: So essentially, while I could *manicure a bush* it wouldn't be because I was caring for it by hand, but because I was treating the bush like a hand. Interesting.

Comment: @Spare Oom: Possibly what crossed my mind is that same thing you're thinkng of. I wondered if the slang 'bush' for 'pubic hair' helped extend use of the word *manicure* from the garden bush to that one. Or the other way round - I've no idea which bush came first in that context!

Comment: @Matt Ellen:  The manicuring of something (including hands) is now more related to being neatly trimmed, which Harrold's answer explains.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. NOAD:

> manicure |ˈmanɪkjʊə|
>
> noun
>
> a cosmetic treatment of the hands involving
> cutting, shaping, and often painting of the nails, removal of the
> cuticles, and softening of the skin.
>
> verb [ trans. ] give a manicure
> to.
>
> **• [usu. as adj. ] ( manicured) trim neatly : manicured lawns.**
>
> ORIGIN late 19th cent.: from French, from Latin manus ‘hand’ + cura
> ‘care.’

Comment: +1 for a good informative answer, but… why “unfortunately”?  Metaphorical and figurative uses like this are part of the beauty of language!

Comment: Just my two cents, but no, the metaphorical use doesn't extend this far so easily; the Latin expands to _care of the hand_ and can't just be inverted to _the hand of care_, thus the only extent to which you can take the metaphor is when caring for the 'hands' of the bush (you would need to define these per bush, obviously.)

Comment: +1 for manicured lawns.  Hedges also, as in Free Dictionary: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/manicure

Comment: Well, **manicured lawns** does not necessarily mean the work was done "by hand".  It could have been done by machine, or letting the sheep graze there for a few days.

Comment: @PLL I thought the term is used only for cosmetic treatment of the hands and the wider meaning makes it more ambiguous – that is why I consider it to be unfortunate. It was not appropriate to express my personal thoughts in this way, however. I shall delete it.

Comment: @GEdgar There's still a 'hand' behind the machine.  The use of sheep would not give the same 'polished' appearance to which the term 'manicured' could be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can manicure a bush, although the phrase 'a manicured lawn' is more common.